# A question about Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem says that we can approximate any polynomial in $C[a,b]$ by using polinomials $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_{k} x^{k}$, and that indicates that monomials $
\left\{x^{k}\right\}_{k \geq 0}
$ is complete in $
L^{2}[a, b]
$. My questions is, recently I read from a book saying that $
\left\{x^{k}\right\}_{k \geq N}
$ is also complete in $
L^{2}[a, b]$, which means that we may use less monomials to approximate a function in $L_2$ and still get close enough. My question is, is  $
\left\{x^{k}\right\}_{k \geq N}
$ really a complete sequence in $
L^{2}[a, b]$? How to prove that and how to understand that a subset of complete monnomials is still complete?

Comment: More precisely, any continuous function can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. I have never seen the term "complete"used in this sense. It is normally used for Hilbert spaces like $L^2$ and the fact that polynomials are complete follows from Weierstrass theorem and two facts: continuous functions are dense in $L^2$ and the uniform norm is stronger than the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: @GReyes yeah I understand that part, but is a system without constant polynomial is complete in $L_2$?

Comment: There's a way you can quickly convince yourself when $0 \notin [a, b]$. Just show that the map taking $f(x)$ to $f(x)x^N$ is a bounded, invertible linear operator on $C[a, b]$. Hence, the fact that $\{x^k\}_{k \ge 0}$ is dense implies $\{x^k \cdot x^N\}_{k \ge 0}$ is dense.

Comment: @user744868 Is this still true when $0\in [a,b]$?

Comment: @maskliesink Honestly, I'm not certain. I don't see an obvious way to get uniform convergence around $0$, and I doubt that there is a way. The map $f(x) \mapsto f(x)x^N$ is certainly not invertible, as every function in the range must map $x$ to $0$. You'd have more luck elevating the problem to $L^2[a, b]$, I think, where $f(x)/x^N$ should still be square-integrable. Measure theory is not my forte, so I can't really help you much further than that.

Answer (score 1):

True even if $0 \in [a,b]$. Take $f \in L^{2}[a,b]$ and follow the following steps:

1) There exists a continuous function $g$ such that $\|f-g\|_2 <\epsilon$

2) Using the fact that $\int_r^{r} |g(x)|^{2} <\epsilon$ for $r>0$ sufficiently small show that there exist a  continuous function $h$ such that $h=0$ in $(-r,r)$ and $\|f-h\|_2 <2\epsilon$.

3) Apply Weiestrass Theorem to $\frac {h(x)} {x^{N}}$.

Comment: Could you explain why $h$ is continuous?

Comment: @maskliesink Step 2) says that $h$ is $0$ in some interval around $0$. That makes $\frac {h{(x)}} {x^{N}}$ continuous.